# python - problem installing beautifulsoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-lab

Hi everyone I hope soneone could help me with this:

I have been trying to install the beautifulsoup4 package and python doesn't seem to find the module. So when I go to conda list it marks that the package is installed however when I try to import it python reports me that there is no module name BS4. I tried to uninstall however when I do python just keeps loading and doesn't execute nothing.[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

```sh
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as beauti
```

This Will Work For You